# r flex dashboard layout with tabs and panels

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am interested in a flexboard layout with two tabs and within each tab the layout be split into three tiles or panels.

This will give me a layout with three panels which is good.

````
---
title: "Panels"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
```

### Chart C

```{r}
```
````

This will give me a layout with two tabs

````
---
title: "Tabs"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Sheet 1

```{r}
```   

### Sheet 2

```{r}
```
````

How can I put these two together so that my layout looks like this below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this under your `YAML` header in the first example you provided:

```
Sheet1
===
```

The `===` will append tabs to your dashboard.

So it would look like:

````
---
title: "Panels"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
Sheet1
===

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}
```

### Chart C

```{r}
```

Sheet2
===
````

etc...

Comment: Thanks Matt, so this will create a sheet and thats how I do it. That will work.

Comment: You can read more about it here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/layouts.html#multiple_pages and if this has answered your question, feel free to accept the answer so others know that it has been answered